# I am unable to identify this hash-type ? is it a base64 hash

Tags: encryption, hash, encoding, passwords

I have been given task to penetrate in our high school LAB and having some issues in identifying a hash type as i am aware of some of the major hashes but cant verify if it is a base64 hash because i just cant decrypt it

1. Hash : 0/922uvfZMC0ZPHMe8Xv2KvsT/E=
2. Hash : dQWVTNLKCjob+lNr3shxrQqAhYE=

The assigned website contains SQL injection bug running ASP .net server

Please help me in identifying the HASH type

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is not about doing school assignments. And apart from it, you should tell us how are you trying to do so? What language are you using? What environment? What have you done to detect the hash type?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "base64 hash". Base64 is an encoding method. What you're looking at is probably a base64-encoded binary hash value.

If you run that base64 string through a base64 decoder, you'll end up with a binary value that is 20 bytes long.

There's no telling how that binary value was created. That is, given a binary value, there's no way to look at it and say, "this was created by the fooby hashing algorithm."

Comment: OK but its probably [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) which is a frequently used hash that creates a 20-byte hash.